# SVN precommit and nullable return types

Tags: php, svn

When committing my plugin to the repo, I'm getting an error that looks like this:

> Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
>   
> ***********************************
>   
> PHP error in: path/to/file.php:
>   
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in path/to/file.php on line 36
>   
> Errors parsing path/to/filephp

Examining the line in question, I see that the `?` is part of one of PHP 7.1's nullable return types:

> `static function foo($bar=null): ?string { ... }`

Note that my readme.txt file correctly notes the minimum PHP version, if that makes any difference to the parser. If not, do I need to remove all my nullable return types for now?

Comment: When you say committing to the repo which repo are you talking about? Is this a WP question? Or a WP.org question? Perhaps this would be better asked on the .org support forums

Comment: @TomJNowell I was wondering about that, but I didn't see many questions like it. That's true, it is a WP.org question since it concerns their SVN plugin repository for use by plugin authors, not WP code itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linting only supports 7.0 and down. Nullable Types are available in PHP 7.1, so 7.1 code will fail. You will have to change it.

Good Luck!